# Creating depandant Select Input in Shiny R

Tags: r, shiny

I am new in R trying to accomplish following functionality in r 
I created a data frame book3

```
Region<- c("Americas", "Asia Pacific","Asia Pacific", "EMEA", "EMEA")


Country<- c("Mexico", "China","India", "Germany", "Spain" )

Rating<- c(5,3,3,2,4)

book3<- data.frame(Region, Country, Rating)
```

I want to pull Region and country which will be defendant. I am trying using this code

ui.R

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(fluidPage(
titlePanel("Test Dashboard "),
sidebarLayout(
sidebarPanel(
selectInput("data1", "Select Region", choices = c(book3$Region)), 

  selectInput("data2", "select country", choices = c(book3$Country))
   ),
mainPanel()


 )))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're creating an input based on data, you need to create the input in the **server.R** so you can access the data. You do this by usng `renderUI` and `uiOutput`. See [here for reference](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/dynamic-ui.html)

Here's a working example. Notice the `renderUI( )` functions in the `server` that generate the `selectInput` based on the data

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
titlePanel("Test Dashboard "),
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            uiOutput("data1"),   ## uiOutput - gets the UI from the server
            uiOutput("data2")
        ),
mainPanel()
))


server <- function(input, output){

    Region<- c("Americas", "Asia Pacific","Asia Pacific", "EMEA", "EMEA")
    Country<- c("Mexico", "China","India", "Germany", "Spain" )
    Rating<- c(5,3,3,2,4)
    book3<- data.frame(Region, Country, Rating, stringsAsFactors = F)

    ## renderUI - renders a UI element on the server
    ## used when the UI element is dynamic/dependant on data
    output$data1 <- renderUI({
        selectInput("data1", "Select Region", choices = c(book3$Region))
    })

    ## input dependant on the choices in `data1`
    output$data2 <- renderUI({
        selectInput("data2", "select country", choices = c(book3$Country[book3$Region == input$data1]))
    })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: This worked well however it does not give me dependent drop down. For example when i select Asia Pacific it should give me the countries like china ,India etc.

Comment: @RahulThakur - it's just a case of making the `selectInput` for `data2` dependant on the choices of `data1`. Please see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [updateSelectInput](http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/updateSelectInput.html) function in the server code, in order to update the choices (and the selected option) of your selectInput fields:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
    updateSelectInput(session, "data1", "Select Region", choices = c(book3$Region))
}
```